# check slideToggle state with if else function & report slideToggle state after each toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slidetoggle

http://jsfiddle.net/vmKVS/

I am trying to understand the state of slideToggle with a little example.

When I toggle the first time the options element turns green.

I would expect the menu element to turn red when I click toggle again, now the 2nd time, since now the options element goes into not visible state and therefore the else part of the function should run, no?

Also when I check the console the values for the slideToggle state do not change, why? Should they not reflect the state of the element after the click second click, so hidden?

What am I doing wrong? I would like to have for the sake of this example, turn the menu red on the second toggle, since then the options element is not visible any more.

I am new to jQuery and programming, so please forgive my blatant mistakes in logic here. Perhaps I have to rethink this from a different viewpoint. This is where you come in, help me understand this please. Thank you.

HTML

```
<div id="menu">MENU</div>
<div id="options">OPTIONS</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#menu').click(function(){

    $('#options').slideToggle();

    var isVisible = $( '#options' ).is( ":visible" );
    var isHidden = $( '#options' ).is( ":hidden" );
    console.log (isVisible);
    console.log (isHidden);

    if ($('#options').is(':visible') === true ){
        $('#options').css('background', '#16a085');
        console.log (isVisible);
    }

    else {
        console.log (isHidden);
        $('#menu').css('background', '#8e44ad');        
    }    
});
```

CSS

```
#menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 200%;
    background: #000000;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

#options {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    font-size: 200%;
    background: #ccc;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: The slideToggle function is asynchronous, so the element isn't really hidden until it completes. Why not use a simple flag instead

Comment: I have no clue about flag, can you point me to the jQUery docs or an example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the documentation for the jQuery :visible and :hidden selectors more thoroughly:

http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

The issue is that the :visible selector will return true if the element that is selected *consumes space* within the layout, and as the width is not zero, this is true.

There are plenty of ways to do what you're after. A nice way is to toggle a class and use that to detect whether the item is toggled:

```
$('#menu').click(function(){

    $('#options').slideToggle().toggleClass('opened');

    var isVisible = $( '#options' ).is( ".opened" );

    if (isVisible === true ){
        $('#options').css('background', '#16a085');
    }

    else {
        $('#menu').css('background', '#8e44ad');        
    }    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vmKVS/1/

Comment: Thank you, this helps! Though I have no clue about being able to toggle classes, where can I find more info on that please? Your example is quite nice. Do you perhaps also have a link to another logic for this, since you say there are so many ways, I am trying to wrap my head round it, perhaps another angle will help? Thank you.

Comment: The toggleClass documentation is here: https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/ Essentially, it adds a class to the selector element(s), and then removes them again on the next click, providing an easy flag that toggles on and off with each click. And because it's adding a class, you can target it in your CSS, too, making your JavaScript cleaner (for example, #options.opened { background: #16a085; }

Comment: Wicked! Thanks heaps!